# Unable to stop code looping multiple times and changing variable

Tags: jquery, loops, attributes

I have created a large table with cells that will display random numbers, I need to be able to set a threshold value against each cell using JQuery, currently this is only working for my first compare, after that when I enter the threshold value it has forgotten what value I compared on my first cell and will just compare all of my previous comparisons to the new threshold value. Unsure how to word this any simpler. Code is below for the compare

```
function OpenDialog(tdID) {
    $('#openThreshold').dialog('open');
    stopTimer();

    $('#btnSaveThreshold').click(function () {
    SetValuesForCompare(tdID);
    });
}

function SetValuesForCompare(tdID) {
    //Set the values ready for comparing the variables (also carry through the cell ID)
    var thrsVal = $('#txtThreshold').val();
    var cellVal = document.getElementById("Cell" + tdID).innerHTML;
    CompareValues(thrsVal, cellVal, tdID);
}

function CompareValues(thrsVal, cellVal, tdID) {
    //compare and choose colour
    if (cellVal < thrsVal) {
        document.getElementById("Cell" + tdID).className = 'red';
    }
    else if (cellVal == thrsVal) {
        document.getElementById("Cell" + tdID).className = 'green';
    }
    else if (cellVal > thrsVal) {
        document.getElementById("Cell" + tdID).className = 'yellow';
    }
    //Close dialog and hide all text boxes
    $('#openThreshold').dialog('close');
    $("#Thrs" + tdID).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class "cellIsSet" or something like that.  Then:

```
function CompareValues(thrsVal, cellVal, tdID) {
    //compare and choose colour
    if (cellVal < thrsVal && !$('#Cell'+tdID).hasClass('cellIsSet')) {
        //document.getElementById("Cell" + tdID).className = 'red';
        $('#Cell'+tdID).addClass('red').addClass('cellIsSet');
    }
    else if (cellVal == thrsVal && !$('#Cell'+tdID).hasClass('cellIsSet')){
        //document.getElementById("Cell" + tdID).className = 'green';
        $('#Cell'+tdID).addClass('green').addClass('cellIsSet');
    }
    else if (cellVal > thrsVal && !$('#Cell'+tdID).hasClass('cellIsSet')) {
        //document.getElementById("Cell" + tdID).className = 'yellow';
        $('#Cell'+tdID).addClass('yellow').addClass('cellIsSet');
    }
    //Close dialog and hide all text boxes
    $('#openThreshold').dialog('close');
    $("#Thrs" + tdID).hide();
}
```

Please note, that I reformatted your `getElementByID` calls, because you are using jQuery anyway.  That way, if the element already has the class `cellIsSet`, it won't try to reformat because of the `&& !$('#Cell'+tdID).hasClass('cellIsSet')` statement.

Comment: Ah, yes that works thank you, I am just trying to learn how to program and I am having some difficulty with certain aspects, I am creating a small project as a starting point, I have a few more questions, would be more appreciative if you could take some time out and help me, doesn't matter if not and yes I know there is a lot of material online but as I can't see to find any for what I am attempting to do. No problem if not.

Comment: @JackHolmes, sure, please join me in the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37394/jquery-help

Comment: Thank you for the offer, however due to me not having any reputation I am unable to communicate via the chat

Comment: Okay, sorry, I think you need 20 to join.  Keep asking questions, and you will be there in no time.  You can also probably get a point by marking a +1 on this answer (not just voting it as the answer... change the 0 to 1).

Comment: Or, you could check out a new feature in Google; HelpOuts.  I just joined today:  https://tee.sandbox.google.com/

Comment: You also need 15 reputation to mark +1 on an answer, kinda limited at the minute, and OK I'll check it out, thank you very much for your time.